# F# Описать функцию, удаляющую из списка каждый второй элемент

Tags: f#

Как описать функцию, удаляющую из списка каждый второй элемент, если нельзя пользоваться встроенными функциями модуля List?

Comment: мб речь идет и  о возвращении, просто такая формулировка задачи ... "описать функцию, удаляющую из списка каждый второй элемент"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в условии сказано, что нельзя использовать стандартные функции из модуля List, то
одно из возможных решений будет следующим:

```
let removeSnd list =
    let rec loop list acc =
        match list with
        | [] -> acc
        | [h] -> h::acc
        | h::_::t -> loop t (h::acc) 

    loop list [] 
    |> List.rev
```

---

Если предположить, что ограничений нет, то советую использовать генераторы списков (последовательностей, массивов). В `F#4.0` добавили подходящую для данного случая функцию [`List.indexed`](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md):

```
let removeSnd2 s = [
    for ind, x in List.indexed s do 
        if ind % 2 = 0 then yield x
    ]
```

Если новая версия по каким - то причинам для вас недоступна, вы можете использовать `Seq.zip` чтобы объединить в кортеж индексы и элементы:

```
let removeSnd1 s = [
    for ind, x in Seq.zip [0..List.length s] s  do 
        if ind % 2 = 0 then yield x
    ]
```

Обратите внимание, что используется именно [`Seq.zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.zip%5b't1,'t2%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) вместо [`List.zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.zip%5b't1,'t2%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), т.к. последняя выбросит исключение при попытке совместить два списка с разным числом элементов.

Для начинающих даже такая простая задача - отличный способ "привыкнуть" использовать функции из стандартных модулей, поэтому привожу несколько вариантов с использованием [`List.mapi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.mapi%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), [`List.foldBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.foldback%5b't,'state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d),[`List.choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.choose%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) соответственно:

```
let removeSnd3 seq = 
    seq 
    |> List.mapi (fun i el -> i, el)            
    |> List.filter (fun (i, _) -> i % 2 = 0) 
    |> List.map snd    

let removeSnd4 lst =
    lst
    |> List.zip [1 .. List.length lst]
    |> List.foldBack
        (fun (i, x) acc -> if i % 2 = 0 then acc else x::acc)
        <| []

let removeSnd5 lst =
    lst
    |> List.zip [1 .. List.length lst]
    |> List.choose
        (function | i, x when i % 2 <> 0 -> Some x |_ -> None)
```

Comment: а тут разве могут различаться список индексов и список элементов?

Comment: Если о `Seq.zip`, то просто чтобы не отнимать единицу: `[0..List.length s - 1]` :-)

Comment: или не изменять условие в цикле на `if ind % 2 <> 0`